# Lat/lon of pixel inside Landsat scene

Tags: landsat, latitude-longitude, modis

How do I find the lat/lon of each pixel inside a landsat scene.
Either the equations for converting i,j to lat/lon or
just a bunch of files, one for each scene.
Background: I have downloaded a bunch of scenes from Greenland and now I want to 
compare them to some MODIS data.  MODIS provides files with lat/lon for every pixel.

Comment: note that you need a georeferenced (or orthorectified) product if you want meaningful Lat/long. What level do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use GDAL_Translate -of XYZ (http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html) to convert the file to gridded X,Y,Z format. Each cell will be represented by an X,Y coordinate followed by Z value as comma separated, optionally with a header line.

If the file is multiband then just use the first band, that should be enough for comparison.